# Windows 7 professional installation

Tags: operating-systems, windows-installer

I am going to install new OS windows 7 professional sp1 and I going to bought from ebay US ,am an Indian is that key valid for Indian region or it araise any issue is bought from different country and license key became invalid

Answer (score 0):

No, if the licence key is genuine you can use it in any country you want.